# Are there ways to get table counts without updated stats in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get all the counts of tables within a specific schema (or owner). I currently am using the code at the bottom, which works, but is really slow. I know of the systems tables `dba_tables` and `all_tables` but we don't have refreshed stats within the past 1.5 years.

Are there other alternatives to this? I've tried looking at all the system tables, but none seem to have updated stats.

```
select
    table_name, 
    owner as schemaname,
    to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as cnt
  from all_tables
  where lower(owner) = 'ownername'
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to count the rows in each table. Stats should not be used as an accurate measure of the row count. However, the fact that you have not refreshed your stats for 1.5 years is quite concerning, unless you have a database that has not had data added in that period. I suspect that you next SO post will be that of a performance problem ;)

Comment: Yeah already running into performance issues, but for that query I put in the post. I'm not doing anything else with stats though